# How to retrieve data from a jquery ajax response that is a list of maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, object

So I have a response from an ajax call that is a **list of maps**. I need to iterate over the response, and from each map in the list, fetch a specific value using the key "schoolName". My code will make clear what I want to do:-

```
 success:function(response){
    response.each(function(index,value){
        console.log(value.get("schoolName"))
    })
}
```

This throws me an error :-   *Menu.html:33 Uncaught TypeError: response.each is not a function*

How do I get the "schoolName" value from all the maps in the response list?

Comment: What does `response` look like?

Comment: Response is a list of maps:-0: {schoolId: 69448, schoolName: "ABC SCHOOL"}
1: {schoolId: 69453, schoolName: "ABCSchool"}
2: {schoolId: 69412, schoolName: "Alianza Educativa"} and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with $.each()

```
$.each(response, function (index, value) {
   console.log(value.schoolName)            
});
```

Source: [jQuery Page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: Now it says "value.get is not a function".

Comment: try to access the response with value.schoolName instead of value.get("schoolName")

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to decode responde. maybe it is in Json?

```
jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

Then, use [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) correctly:

```
success:function(response){
    jQuery.each(jQuery.parseJSON(response), function(index, value){
        console.log(value.get("schoolName"))
    })
}
```

To be more accurate, a response template might help

Comment: 0: {schoolId: 69448, schoolName: "ABC SCHOOL"}
1: {schoolId: 69453, schoolName: "ABCSchool"}
2: {schoolId: 69412, schoolName: "Alianza Educativa"}

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an object, you can use [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each). Also just use dot notation to access `schoolName`:

```
success:function(response){
    $.each(response, function(index,value){
        console.log(value.schoolName)
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

not sure what your response is like, but if `schoolName` is a key of an object and your response is an array of objects, you can do:

```
(response) => {
   for (let i of response) {
      console.log(i.schoolName);
   }
}
```